# How to use material 2 toolbar

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am using material2 card etc but getting error while trying to add toolbar

app.component.html

```
<md-toolbar [color]="red">
  <span>My Application Title</span>
</md-toolbar>
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import {OVERLAY_PROVIDERS} from "@angular2-material/core";

// Material 2 
import { MdCoreModule } from '@angular2-material/core'
import { MdButtonModule } from '@angular2-material/button';
import { MdCardModule } from '@angular2-material/card';
import { MdRadioModule } from '@angular2-material/radio';
import { MdCheckboxModule } from '@angular2-material/checkbox'
import { MdTooltipModule } from '@angular2-material/tooltip';
import { MdSliderModule } from '@angular2-material/slider';
import { MdToolbarModule,MdToolbarRow } from '@angular2-material/toolbar';


import 'hammerjs' ;

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    MdCoreModule.forRoot() , MdCardModule.forRoot() , MdButtonModule.forRoot() , MdRadioModule.forRoot() ,
    MdCheckboxModule.forRoot() , MdTooltipModule.forRoot() , MdSliderModule.forRoot() ,MdToolbarModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [OVERLAY_PROVIDERS],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

i am getting error

> zone.js:388Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors: Can't
>   bind to 'color' since it isn't a known property of 'md-toolbar'.
>   1. If 'md-toolbar' is an Angular component and it has 'color' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
>   2. If 'md-toolbar' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schema' of this component
>   to suppress this message.  ("
>
> ][color]="red">   My Application
>   Title "): AppComponent@39:12 'md-toolbar' is not a
>   known element:
>   1. If 'md-toolbar' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
>   2. If 'md-toolbar' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schema' of this component
>   to suppress this message. ("

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think this is not related to your error, but color should be from the type "primary" | "accent" | "warn". [color]="red" is not a valid value. color="primary" is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

now it is working after changes in app.compoent.ts

```
    import { MdToolbarModule,MdToolbarRow } from '@angular2-material/toolbar';

  imports: [
    MdToolbarModule.forRoot(),   

  ],
```

Answer (score 1):

Also I found that if you encounter issues such as md- whatever is an unknown element, change it to mat- whatever.  Examples I found are md-toolbar, md-icon, and md-menu. I had to change all of these to mat- and it worked.  Also I had to change the mdMenu to matMenu and viola!

Answer (score 1):

### app.module.ts file

2 Changes

1. `import {MatToolbarModule} from '@angular/material/toolbar';`
2. ```
   imports: [
     MatToolbarModule
   ],
   ```